Creating a gradient colour in Pie Radar Chart
I want to create pie radar chart in Excel that represents the maturity level of 5 different fields (let's call them A, B, C, D and E) on a scale of 0-100. It's very similar to this problem - How to make a Pie radar chart so, I've tried to follow this to some extent. However, my problem differs in the following two points -

I want to have text gridline labels instead of numeric values, i.e. instead of 0, 20, 40, 60, 80 and 100, I want to display Very Low, Low, Medium, High and Very High.

I would ideally like the colour to be a gradient based on the value of the segment, i.e. darker shade of blue for every concentric circle as the value increases.


For reference, this is sort of what I'm looking to make with Excel (pardon my barely passable PowerPoint skills) -

How can I go about making this chart in Excel?

Please don't. What's wrong with a stacked column chart? Why is the circular representation relevant to the data or helpful to the reader? Note that circles take up way more space than rectangles for the same amount of information. Also your outer rings will be hugely over-represented by large areas of ink relative to inner circles.
